# Inline styling font-family not working on gmail and outlook

Tags: web, html-email, web-frontend

I have create a template and have use a google font family 'Ubuntu' as follow:. However when viewing on gmail or outlook, it is display the text in Arial. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks you.

```
<td align="center" style="color: #fff;font-size: 29px;padding: 30px 0 15px 0;font-weight:500;font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;">Text</td>
```

In the head, I have added the link to call the font as follow:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though media queries are supported in Gmail and Gmail app, web fonts are not supported. The only fonts you can use in Gmail are Roboto and a few others that Gmail already serves thru its own CSS.

**Current list of fonts available to use on Gmail are:**

- Google Sans
- Google Sans Medium
- Product Sans
- Roboto Italic
- Roboto Regular
- Roboto Medium
- Roboto Bold

Checked on :01/03/2019

[Here is an article](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts) that shows you a breakdown of you a breakdown of email clients that support web fonts.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** Font list updated

Comment: Syfer is correct. The same issue occurs with Outlook and Notes, which have spotty acceptance of webfonts. You'd think Gmail would at least work with Google Fonts, but the answer is no.